# Why does the code to model UNTIL/REPEAT require new keyword?

Tags: scala

I've been told that Scala provides capability to model `UNTIL, REPEAT` control flow.

While studying the capability, I've found the code:

```scala
// ref: https://gist.github.com/metasim/7503601
def REPEAT(body: => Unit) = new {
  def UNTIL(condition: => Boolean): Unit = {
    body
    if (condition) ()
    else UNTIL(condition)
  }
}

// test code
REPEAT {
  x = x + 1
} UNTIL (x > 3)
```

Why is the `new` keyword in `REPEAT` function needed?

Comment: Because `UNTIL` is a method, not a name of a(n eager) function.

Comment: Then, `new {}` create an object? as I know, method should be in an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new { def ...}` construct creates a new anonymous object with [structural type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) `AnyRef{def ...}`:

```
scala> val aa = new { def kk = "bb" }
aa: AnyRef{def kk: String}
```

Your `UNTIL` method is accessible because of feature called "reflective access of structural type member", and you should also have an `import scala.language.reflectiveCalls`, at least in Scala 2.11.2 as a result of [SIP 18: Modularizing Language Features](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/modularizing-language-features.html):

```
scala> aa.kk
<console>:9: warning: reflective access of structural type member method kk should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.reflectiveCalls visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.reflectiveCalls'
or by setting the compiler option -language:reflectiveCalls.
See the Scala docs for value scala.language.reflectiveCalls for a discussion
why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
              aa.kk
                 ^
res0: String = bb
```

Note, that it's a little bit slower than defining `class Repeatable {def UNTIL = ...}`, because  (for JVM) your `REPEAT` function just returns `Object` (AnyRef) and there is no type to cast from it, so Scala invokes `UNTIL` using reflection. It also didn't introduce some synthetic class because structural type can match any existing class (any other class with appropriate `UNTIL` method).

Comment: Thanks! Somewhat profound than I expected. In summary, duck-typed object(AnyRef) looks like an anonymous(?) object. It doesn't require class, just need implementation. But I have one more question. Even if I didn't import reflectiveCalls, my code works. Only scala interpreter requires to import that package?

Comment: Yrw. object itself have a class (formal type) AnyRef, duck-typing allows it to have real type with appropriate signature and call its methods by reflection. Your code works, but you still receive this warning (full warning text is available with "scala -feature")